# Count all duplicates in ListView column. C#

Tags: c#, windows, listview, listviewitem

I'm creating a software for a marketplace and want to create a listview that counts all the duplicate values inside a column.

This count will show how many items were oftenly bought by buyers.

This is the concept of the ListView should be.
It counts from column of ListView1, and put the duplicates, count it, and display the data inside of ListView2.

[image: Concept]

I need to know:

- How to Count all the duplicated value inside the "Purchased Items" column.
- And display the count result inside another ListView with the value itself.

*Note: In this case, the value inside the "Name" is an Item and the "Purchased Items" is a Subitem. Those data were from simply typing in a textbox and clicking on a button.*

Comment: Anyway, if you think this is a duplicate & there's an exact answer to that. Please provide me a link to it, huge thanks!.

Comment: Where are you getting this values from, a database?

Comment: No, just by manualling adding it via a textbox & button.
(it'll be way more harder for me to do that lol)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Group the items of the input `ListView` by the values of the second `ColumnHeader` (index = 1) to get `IEnumerable<IGrouping<string, ListViewItem>>`, then use the elements (of type `IGrouping<string, ListViewItem>`) `Key` property and `Count` method to create the `ListViewItem` objects of the output `ListView`.

Here's a one liner:

```cs
listView2.Items.AddRange(listView1.Items
    .Cast<ListViewItem>()
    .GroupBy(x => x.SubItems[1].Text, StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase)
    .Select(x => new ListViewItem(new[] { x.Key, x.Count().ToString() }))
    .ToArray());
```

Answer (score 0):

The outcome you want can be achieved using `System.Linq.GroupBy` for the logic and `DataGridView` (Winforms Example) for the views:

[image]

The amount of code to write is small! Just use Data Binding [Winforms](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.listcontrol.datasource?view=windowsdesktop-6.0), [Xamarin](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/listview/data-and-databinding), [WPF](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/wpf/controls/listview-overview?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8#binding-data-to-a-listview) for two lists:

**First** make two classes containing the properties you wish to display:

```
internal class UserPurchase
{       
    public string Name { get; internal set; } // Internal makes item ReadOnly in view
    public string Purchase { get; internal set; }
}
```

and

```
internal class PurchasedItem
{
    public string Description { get; internal set; }
    public int Count { get; internal set; }
}
```

**Then** declare two `BindingList` (Winforms example) or `ObservableCollection` (others).

```
internal BindingList<UserPurchase> PurchasesByUser { get; } = new BindingList<UserPurchase>();
internal BindingList<PurchasedItem> PurchasedByItem { get; } = new BindingList<PurchasedItem>();
```

This shows how to attach the bindings in Winforms (for other platforms use the xaml). As a result `DataGridView` will now generate columns automatically using the properties of the two classes.

```
protected override void OnHandleCreated(EventArgs e)
{
    base.OnHandleCreated(e);
    if (!DesignMode)
    {
        // Bind the lists to the UI element to display them.
        dataGridView1.DataSource = PurchasesByUser;
        dataGridView2.DataSource = PurchasedByItem;
        initList1();
    }
}
```

Here is the list initializer which populates `List1` **PurchasesByUser** then applies `System.Linq.GroupBy` on `List1` to calculate `List2` **PurchasedByItem**:

```
private void initList1()
{
    XElement xsource = XElement.Parse(source);
    XElement[] xusers = xsource.Elements("user").ToArray();
    foreach (XElement xuser in xusers)
    {
        XElement[] xpurchases = xuser.Element("items").Elements("item").ToArray();
        foreach (XElement xpurchase in xpurchases)
        {
            var xname = xuser.Element("name");
            // Every time you add a record to the list, it appears in the View automatically.
            PurchasesByUser.Add(new UserPurchase { Name = (string)xname, Purchase = (string)xpurchase });
        }
    }
    // Make what is essentially a list *of* lists using System.Linq.GroupBy
    var groups = 
        PurchasesByUser.GroupBy(purchase => purchase.Purchase);
    foreach (var group in groups)
    {
        // Decoding the Group:
        Debug.WriteLine(
            $"The group '{group.Key}' holds {group.Count()} items");
        Debug.WriteLine(
            $"The customers are { string.Join(",", group.ToList().Select(item=>item.Name))}");
        var byItem = new PurchasedItem { Description = group.Key, Count = group.Count() };
        PurchasedByItem.Add(byItem);
    }
}
```

**Finally** to model your database (with subitems), I used this string in Xml format:

```
const string source =
    @"<purchases>
        <user>
            <name>John Doe</name>
            <items>
                <item>Shoes</item>
                <item>T-Shirts</item>
                <item>Jeans</item>
            </items>
        </user>
        <user>
            <name>Rick Astley</name>
            <items>
                <item>Baseball bat</item>
                <item>Sandwich</item>
                <item>T-Shirts</item>
                <item>Shoes</item>
            </items>
        </user>
        <user>
            <name>Jane Doe</name>
            <items>
                <item>Shoes</item>
                <item>T-Shirts</item>
            </items>
        </user>
        <user>
            <name>Anonymous</name>
            <items>
                <item>Laptop</item>
            </items>
        </user>
        <user>
            <name>Joe Mm.</name>
            <items>
                <item>Milk</item>
                <item>Shoes</item>
            </items>
        </user>
    </purchases>";
```

This is just one approach of course but your question is a good way to demonstrate combining concepts from `System.Linq` `System.Xml.Linq` and Data Binding. I posted my code on [GitHub](https://github.com/IVSoftware/purchased_items.git) if you'd like to experiment with it.

Answer (score 0):

So if I understand you want to have another listview with duplicates and the count?

If so you can create a List<> and then add that item into the list in this case will be a string I believe, maybe something like this? This is just a console app for demonstration.

```
List<string> myList = new List<string>();

myList.Add("One");
myList.Add("Two");
myList.Add("Three");
myList.Add("One");
myList.Add("Two");
myList.Add("Four");

List<string> noDupes = myList.Distinct().ToList();


foreach(string dupe in noDupes)
{
    Console.WriteLine(dupe);
}

Console.WriteLine(noDupes.Count());
```

Comment: This shows non dupes, so you can then do opposite for dupes to a new list

Answer (score 0):

Given the next list:

```
List<myClass> items = new List<myClass>()
{
    new myClass() { Name = "John Doe", Item = "Shoes" },
    new myClass() { Name = "John Doe", Item = "T-Shirt" },
    new myClass() { Name = "John Doe", Item = "Jeans" },
    new myClass() { Name = "Rick Astley", Item = "Baseball bat" },
    new myClass() { Name = "Rick Astley", Item = "Sandwich" },
    new myClass() { Name = "Rick Astley", Item = "T-Shirt" },
    new myClass() { Name = "Rick Astley", Item = "Shoes" },
    new myClass() { Name = "Jane Doe", Item = "Shoes" },
    new myClass() { Name = "Jane Doe", Item = "T-Shirt" },
    new myClass() { Name = "Joe Mm.", Item = "Shoes" },
    new myClass() { Name = "Joe Mm.", Item = "Milk" },
};
```

You can group and count in this way:

```
var l = items.GroupBy(group => group.Item)
                .Select(n => new { Item = n.Key, Count = n.Count() })
                .ToList();
```

The result:

```
Item: Shoes  Count: 4
Item: T-Shirt  Count: 3
Item: Jeans  Count: 1
Item: Baseball bat  Count: 1
Item: Sandwich  Count: 1
Item: Milk  Count: 1
```